# 外部アプリケーションを起動する、ファイルを関連付けられたソフトで開く

Tags: c#

お世話になっております。
[参考サイト１](http://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/process/shell.html)
[参考サイト２](http://jeanne.wankuma.com/tips/csharp/process/startinfo.html)
上のサイトを参考にしたのですが、うまくいきませんでした。
開きたいexeはdbview.exeと言うexeです。

```
  string inputFolderName = @"C:\tmp"
    string sample1 = "sample1.DB";
    string sample2 = "sample2.DB";
    string sample3 = "sample3.DB";
    string[] dbName = new string[] { sample1, sample2, sample3 };

    for (int i = 0; i < dbName.Length; i++) {
        string FileName = "dbview.exe";
        string Directory = Path.Combine(inputFolderName , MasterName[i]);
        string Arguments = Directory;

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = FileName;
        process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
```

エラーとしては
'dbview.exe' が見つかりません。名前を正しく入力したかどうかを確認してから、やり直してください。
と言われます。

今回の目的は、このdbviewを起動さ.dbファイルをアクセスDBに変換したいと考えています。

dbviewのヘルプにCommand-line argumentsがいくつか用意されているみたいなのですが、そのコマンドが
**dbview.exe c:\data\country.db**
と記載がありました。

process.StartInfo.Argumentsにdbview.exe c:\data\country.dbのコマンドラインを入力してもダメだったのですが、何がダメなのでしょうか？

ご教授よろしくお願いします。

※dbviewが保存されているところはデスクトップのフォルダになります。
その中の名前は’DBView.exe’となってます。
string FileName = "dbview.exe";部分を大文字にして試してもダメでした。

以下、dbview.exe ヘルプ全文

```
Paradox Viewer supports the wide list of command-line arguments.
You may use these extended parameters to control the any functionality.

dbview.exe [<paradox_file> [/e] [csv|txt|htm|xml|xls|sav|sql] [destination_file]] [/t] [/nocreate] [/ansi|oem] [/pass=] [/noini] [/norecno] [/lang=]


A few samples:
- to start the tool in standard interactive mode
dbview.exe

- to start the tool and open the Paradox file automatically
dbview.exe c:\data\country.db

- to convert the Paradox table (country.db) to CSV-file (country.csv)
dbview.exe c:\data\country.db /e csv

- to convert the Paradox table (country.db) to text file with custom file name
dbview.exe c:\data\country.db /e txt d:\output\data0026.dat

- to save the Paradox table to MS Excel spreadsheet
dbview.exe d:\country.db /e xls

- to publish the Paradox table to web-page (html-format)
dbview.exe d:\country.db /e htm x:\inetpub\wwwroot\countries.htm

- to generate xml-file from Paradox table
dbview.exe d:\country.db /e xml

- to generate SPSS-file from Paradox table
dbview.exe d:\country.db /e sav

- to generate SQL-dump from Paradox table
dbview.exe d:\country.db /e sql

- to generate SQL-dump without CREATE TABLE statement
dbview.exe d:\country.db /e sql d:\country.sql /nocreate

- to convert the Paradox table to CSV-file and include the header line
dbview.exe c:\data\country.db /e csv d:\country.csv /t

- to open the Paradox file in OEM codepage
dbview.exe c:\data\country.db /oem

- to open the password protected Paradox file
dbview.exe c:\data\country.db /pass=peter

- to start the tool but do not save this session in configuration file
dbview.exe c:\data\country.db /noini

- to start the viewer with custom language file
dbview.exe c:\data\country.db /lang=LANG\german.lng

- to save the Paradox table to without column with record number
dbview.exe d:\country.db /e xls /norecno
```

**追記**

helpにこのようなものもありました。
Paradox Viewer supports also the configuration file where you may customize any parameter for viewer.
You may activate this configuration file via command-line argument

dbview.exe [ [/f ]

Also you may use the next parameters:
Format=CSV ' destination export format (CSV or TXT or HTM or XML or XLS or XLW or SAV or SQL or MDB or ADO or WK1)
FileName=country1.csv ' destination file name for export
SkipHeader=1/0 ' skip or include header in exported file
BreakExportOnException=1/0 ' continue if error occured during file parse
Filter=(Area > 1000000) ' expression to limit the records for export
FirstRow=1 ' first row
LastRow=15 ' last row
FieldList=CODE;NAME ' field list
Sort=CODE ' field name to order
ExportSource=STRUCTURE ' DATA or STRUCTURE or GENERAL
CreateTableSQL=0/1 ' skip or include the CREATE TABLE statement for SQL export
Password=qx2z8yas ' required password to read the file
MDBUserID=peter ' UserID for export to MS Access
MDBPassword=p19ht ' Password for export to MS Access
IncludeRecNoInExport=0/1 ' include or exclude the record number in saved file
Language=german.lng ' default language file with translated interface
CSVExportDelimiter=, ' default field delimiter for CSV export
CSVExportQualifier=" ' default text qualifier for CSV export
CodePage=OEM ' use DOS/OEM codepage to read the file

Any parameter can be included in config file or removed from config-file.

C#
.net3.5
windows8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windowsの既定の設定ではデスクトップフォルダーには`PATH`が設定されていませんので、ファイル名のみで`Process.Start`を実行することはできません。

対策としては以下のようなものになります。

- コード中に`dbview.exe`の絶対パスを明示する
- `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "dbview.exe")`でデスクトップのパスを追加する
- カレントディレクトリを明示する
- カレントディレクトリ(おそらく実行ファイルのディレクトリ)に`dbview.exe`を移動する
- `PATH`にデスクトップを追加する。

Comment: #pgrhoさん　pathの指定をすることで起動はできました。アプリケーションは実行することはできたのですが、その後dbファイルをアクセスファイルに変換するというとこまでができなかったのですが、argumentsの引数が足りないという事でしょうか？

Comment: @BAKZ 私はParadox Viewerなるソフトを使ったことがないのでわかりませんが、ヘルプを見る限り`/e csv hoge.csv`や`/e sql fuga.sql`など適当な形式でファイルを出力してから自分でAccess形式のファイルに書き込まないといけないのでは。

Comment: ＠pgrhoさん　そうですか。ありがとうございます。コマンドlineのhelpがまだありましたので追記いたしました。この情報でなにか自動的に出力できそうなヒントがあれば教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: ＠pgrhoさん 引数に　/e MDBと与えたらできました。ありがとうございます。